# Angular 2 not sending POST request properly

Tags: angular, typescript, express, angular-http

I tried making a simple POST request through Angular 2 HTTP and the request seems to not be sent properly, here is the code that i use to send the POST request:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import  'rxjs/add/operator/map';    

/** ... */

public sendData(s: string, k: any) {
        let h = new Headers();
        h.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        h.append('Accept', 'application/json');

        let content = JSON.stringify({
            username: s,
            key: k
        });
        console.log(content);

        return this.httpService.post(SERVER_URL, content, {
        headers: h
        })
        .map((res: Response) => {
            return res.json();
        });
    }
```

and the code for the Express server (in Typescript) is as follows:

```
public handleWhitelistRequest(req: Request, res: Response) {
    let out: boolean;
    console.log("post request received"); //DEBUG
    if (req.body.key) {
        out = wl.submit(req.body.username, req.body.key);
    } else {
        out = wl.submit(req.body.username, {});
    }

    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");     
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    res.json({
        username: req.body.username,
        success: out
    });
}
```

Do not worry about what `wl` is, it is only a defined `const`.
Calling the Angular 2 code above to send requests gives out the 'CORS' error message, which I believe should be handled by appending the headers as above.
Furtheremore, **the 'post request received' message is not logged to the console which concerns me.**

Extra details and debugs that I have done:

- Using Postman to send POST requests to the server works as intended, even logging 'post request received'.
- GET requests behave as intended (even from Angular).

I believe that the problem might me in the Angular code not sending the content properly, however - I'm not 100% sure. Thank you very much for helping.

Comment: how are you calling it? I have a feeling it's your headers not being set on the request...

Comment: @MikeTung calling the sendData function? i do it as follows:
`this.ps.sendData(s,key) .subscribe((data: any) => {this.lastReq = data.success ? "wl-succ" : "wl-fail";})}`

Comment: check network tab for headers

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
    import { Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';

    constructor(private http: Http) {}


    public sendData(uName, k) {
       let content = {
           username: uName,
           key: k
       };
       return this.http.post(SERVER_URL,content)
       .subscribe((res: any) => {
          console.log(res);
       });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to append those headers before sending the request, you also do not need to `JSON.stringify()` the content before posting it.

```
public sendData(s: string, k: any) {
    let content = {
        username: s,
        key: k
    };

    return this.httpService.post(SERVER_URL, content)
        .map((res: Response) => res.json());
}
```

Also, your HTTP method will not fire until you've called it with a `subscribe()`, so I'm assuming you're calling this `sendDate()` method in another component and subscribing to the response.

Please note that the regular HTTP will eventually be depreciated and replaced with HTTP Client.

This is how you would do this using HTTP Client, you can read more [here](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-http/)

```
public sendData(s: string, k: any) {
    let content = {
        username: s,
        key: k
    };

    return this.httpService.post<any>(SERVER_URL, content);
}
```